# Accessing method from activity that will start another activity from a class

Tags: java, android

Hi i'm developing an app that will use a fingerprint authentication to login, I create a class named FingerprintHandler and from that class i'm calling a method that will start another activity if fingerprint auth succeed, i also tried passing the context to the method but i still get an null object reference

[image]

FingerprintHanlder Class

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public class FingerprintHandler extends FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {

private Context context;

public FingerprintHandler(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public void startAuth(FingerprintManager fingerprintManager,  FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject){
    CancellationSignal cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();
    fingerprintManager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal,0, this,null);
}


private void update(String s, boolean b){
    MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
    EditText etEmail,etPassword;

    TextView tvFeedback = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.tvFeedback);
    tvFeedback.setText(s);

    if(b == false) {
        tvFeedback.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorAccent));
    } else {
        tvFeedback.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorPrimary));
        m.login(context.getApplicationContext(),context,"user","password");

    }

}
```

}

MainActivity Class Method

```
public void login(final Context c1,final Context c, final String user, final String password) {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    dialog.setMessage("Authenticating ...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, dBhelper.URL + "app-ess-login", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("test: ", response);
            try {
                JSONObject collections = new JSONObject(response);
                is_auth = collections.getInt("auth");
                JSONArray jsonArrayUsers = collections.getJSONArray("user");
                if(is_auth > 0) {
                    dBhelper.truncate();
                    for(int x = 0; x < jsonArrayUsers.length(); x++) {
                        JSONObject user = jsonArrayUsers.getJSONObject(x);
                        dBhelper.insertData(user.getInt("id"), user.getString("formal_name"), user.getString("email"), user.getString("job_title_name"), user.getString("schedule"));
                    }
                    dBhelper.username = user;
                    dBhelper.password = password;

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(c, BundyClock.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(c, "Incorrect Email or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(c, "Error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", user);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    com.example.ess.AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: can you also share your error log

Comment: Have you tried declaring an intent like `intent = new Intent (this, BundyClock.class)`?

Comment: @Steyrix yes, still gets null object reference

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: @MikeM. i will update this, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `startActivity(intent)` And this is where you see the error. Why are you seeing this error?

1. You are calling `MainActivity m = new MainActivity();` and `m.login()`. Activities are not a regular Java class and you need a lot of inheritance (BaseContext, etc) to make it work correctly. If you want to use the activity, you need to call `startActivity(Intent)` so it has all the necessary inheritance.
2. Since you are not *starting* MainActivity, it does not have proper context. When you call `startActivity(intent)` in your `onResponse` callback, it throws Null Pointer Exception as it does not have proper context.

How to fix this?

1. Do not use `m.login()`. You should move this method to some other class (not an activity). or make `login` a static method so that it is no tied to the MainActivity.
2. Use `context.startActivity(intent)` since you are passing `context` in login method.

Comment: Thank you so much, i fixed it using context.startActivity(intent) :)